# Profiled performance of len(set) vs. set.__len__() in Python 3

Tags: python, performance, profiling, set

While profiling my Python's application, I've discovered that `len()` seems to be a very expensive one when using sets. See the below code:

```
import cProfile

def lenA(s):
    for i in range(1000000):
        len(s);

def lenB(s):
    for i in range(1000000):
        s.__len__();

def main():
    s = set();
    lenA(s);
    lenB(s);

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cProfile.run("main()","stats");
```

According to profiler's stats below, `lenA()` seems to be 14 times slower than `lenB()`:

```
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall  filename:lineno(function)
      1    1.986    1.986    3.830    3.830  .../lentest.py:5(lenA)
1000000    1.845    0.000    1.845    0.000  {built-in method len}
      1    0.273    0.273    0.273    0.273  .../lentest.py:9(lenB)
```

Am I missing something? Currently I use `__len__()` instead of `len()`, but the code looks dirty :(

Comment: Why are you using `cProfile` instead of `timeit`? The former is for finding bottlenecks in large programs, and sacrifices some accuracy on the small scale for it. The latter is for measuring the overall performance of tiny snippets relatively precisely. `timeit` should be the first choice for microbenchmarks like this. And for me, it indicates a less extreme difference (0.0879 µs per `len` call, 0.158 µs per `.__len__` call => `len` being 70% slower).

Comment: Thanks @delnan, I'm quite new in Python. Using `timeit` I also get similar ratio. Indeed, my program is much larger than the above code, but it surprised me that `len()` function appeared as one of major bottlenecks. OK, so I will just ignore `len()` and focus on my own functions, right?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Obviously, `len` has some overhead, since it does a function call and translates `AttributeError` to `TypeError`. Also, `set.__len__` is such a simple operation that it's bound to be very fast in comparison to just about anything, but I still don't find anything like the 14x difference when using `timeit`:

```
In [1]: s = set()

In [2]: %timeit s.__len__()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 197 ns per loop

In [3]: %timeit len(s)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 130 ns per loop
```

You should always just call `len`, not `__len__`. If the call to `len` is the bottleneck in your program, you should rethink its design, e.g. cache sizes somewhere or calculate them without calling `len`.

Comment: +1: In particular, don't prematurely optimize. Benchmarks can be flawed, and as you might have seen now, three benchmarks will likely return three different results; and you might end up benchmarking something completely different than you expected with such a micro-benchmark. Obivously, `len` can not be faster, as it calls `__len__`. But that is about all that is certain.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: actually, I just looked at my own results again and I only now see that `len` is faster than `__len__`. Not sure how that came about.

Comment: `s.__len__` does a function call also, *and* has to look up an attribute. That outweighs the global lookup of `len`.

Comment: @FredFoo: `len()` doesn't have to look up `__len__` for built-in types. In fact, it *never looks up `__len__` directly*. It looks up the `tp_as_sequence` pointer, traversing to the `sq_length` attribute of that struct. Custom Python classes fill that slot with a lookup of the `__len__` attribute. For `set` and `list` and such, there is no need for that last step.

Answer (score 7):

This is an interesting observation about the profiler, which has nothing to do with the actual performance of the len function. You see, in the profiler stats, there are two lines concerning `lenA`:

```
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall  filename:lineno(function)
      1    1.986    1.986    3.830    3.830  .../lentest.py:5(lenA)
1000000    1.845    0.000    1.845    0.000  {built-in method len}
```

...while there is only one line concerning `lenB`:

```
      1    0.273    0.273    0.273    0.273  .../lentest.py:9(lenB)
```

The profiler has timed each single call from `lenA` to `len`, but timed `lenB` as a whole. Timing a call always adds some overhead; in the case of lenA you see this overhead multiplied a million times.

Comment: I think that your point is absolutely precise. It's all about `cProfile`'s overhead, not about performance of `len` function.

Answer (score 1):

This was going to be a comment but after larsman's comment on his controversial results and the result I got, I think it is interesting to add my data to the thread.

Trying more or less the same setup I got the contrary the OP got, and in the same direction commented by larsman:

```
12.1964105975   <- __len__
6.22144670823   <- len()

C:\Python26\programas>
```

The test:

```
def lenA(s):
    for i in range(100):
        len(s);

def lenB(s):
    for i in range(100):
        s.__len__();

s = set()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    from timeit import timeit
    print timeit("lenB(s)", setup="from __main__ import lenB, s")
    print timeit("lenA(s)", setup="from __main__ import lenA, s")
```

This is activepython 2.6.7 64bit in win7