# Why are __getitem__(key) and get(key) significantly slower than [key]?

Tags: python, profiling, benchmarking

It was my understanding that brackets were nothing more than a wrapper for `__getitem__`.  Here is how I benchmarked this:

First, I generated a semi-large dictionary.

```
items = {}
for i in range(1000000):
    items[i] = 1
```

Then, I used cProfile to test the following three functions:

```
def get2(items):
    for k in items.iterkeys():
        items.get(k)

def magic3(items):
    for k in items.iterkeys():
        items.__getitem__(k)

def brackets1(items):
    for k in items.iterkeys():
        items[k]
```

The results looked like so:

```
         1000004 function calls in 3.779 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.779    3.779 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    2.135    2.135    3.778    3.778 dict_get_items.py:15(get2)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  1000000    1.644    0.000    1.644    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'iterkeys' of 'dict' objects}


         1000004 function calls in 3.679 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.679    3.679 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    2.083    2.083    3.679    3.679 dict_get_items.py:19(magic3)
  1000000    1.596    0.000    1.596    0.000 {method '__getitem__' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'iterkeys' of 'dict' objects}


         4 function calls in 0.136 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.136    0.136 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.136    0.136    0.136    0.136 dict_get_items.py:11(brackets1)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'iterkeys' of 'dict' objects}
```

Is the issue in the way I am benchmarking?  I tried replacing the bracket access with a simple "pass" to ensure that the data was actually being accessed, and found that "pass" was running much quicker.  My interpretation of this was that the data was indeed being accessed.  I've also tried appending to a new list, which gave similar results.

Comment: my guess (and it's just a guess) is that the `[]` doesn't create a new stack level while the other do. interesting.

Comment: For microbenchmarks like this, `timeit` is better as it's very precise, removes several pitfalls, and automatically loops the statement for sufficent data without taking too long. I doubt it changes much about the result, though the slowdown may be less severe. Edit @Not_a_Golfer: All three methods should be C code, and C stack frames are quite cheap.

Comment: Maybe brackets use lazy evaluation? Try doing a sum of all the results to make sure they're used.

Comment: Also, i wonder what happens if you don't iterate over that same list while using get[k], could be that it's taking advantage of having some kind of iterator already pointing to the current key?

Comment: using `dis` to view the bytecode it, shows that using `__getitem__` adds 2 more bytecode ops, one of them is `CALL_FUNCTION`.

Comment: Quite outlandish guesses, guys. I don't think the dictionary is aware of all its iterators (though the inverse is likely), and there is no lazy evaluation to speak of in Python.

Comment: I tried for k in range(0, 1000000000) | items[k] and it seemed to take as long as the "slower" versions; don't have anything for profiling handy to get exact results though.

Comment: @delnan it's 23:30 and i want to do something more entertaining now, this question just looked interesting enough to make an outlandish guess :)

Comment: @Torp I'm not complaining :) I'm just playing devil's advocate.

Comment: here are my experiments with `dis`. looks like a good enough reason to me: http://pastebin.com/UzHGbSmg

Comment: AFAIK the `CALL_FUNCTION` op means a new stack level is created in the python VM, it's not a C land stack frame.

Comment: We may have to go and dig in the interpreter source code. I *believe* there's a special case for `builtin_function_or_method`, as creating a Python frame for them does not make any sense. @Not_a_Golfer I would have guessed that too, but the difference OP reports is quite large. Maybe it's just due to a bad profiling method, the figures `timeit` gives me fit the addition of a few opcodes.

Comment: @delnan not sure how heavy it is, but at the very least using those functions requires resolving them (each time, right? this stuff is not optimized afaik), while the operator has its own opcode, this can probably be a bit time consuming.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Certainly, that's why I'm not surprised *that* it's slower. It's just the magnitude which surprises me, but again, that might be due to the profiling method.

Comment: @delnan using cProfile I found `get` and `__getitem__` to be around x2 slower than `[]`, but nothing near these results.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer - yea, there is probably some overhead from the profiler. Just for completenes some [timeit results](http://pastebin.com/7PU7bNks)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778691/performance-of-lenset-vs-set-len-in-python-3 for a discussion on the profile overhead.

Comment: @delnan @Dan I just noticed the count in the output. the last function says `***4*** function calls` while the first two say `1000004 function calls`. WTF is up with that? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, the disassembly posted by Not_a_Golfer:

```
>>> d = {1:2}
>>> dis.dis(lambda: d[1])
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (d)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 BINARY_SUBSCR       
              7 RETURN_VALUE   

>>> dis.dis(lambda: d.get(1))
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (d)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (get)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE  

>>> dis.dis(lambda: d.__getitem__(1))
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (d)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (__getitem__)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

Now, getting the benchmarking right is obviously important to read anything into the results, and I don't know enough to help much there. But assuming there really is a difference (which makes sense to me), here's my guesses about why there is:

1. `dict.get` simply "does more"; it has to check if the key is present, and if not return its second argument (which defaults to `None`). This means there's some form of conditional or exception-catching, so I am completely unsurprised that this would have different timing characteristics to the more basic operation of retrieving the value associated with a key.
2. Python has a specific bytecode for the "subscription" operation (as demonstrated in the disassembly). The builtin types, including `dict`, are implemented primarily in C and their implementations do not necessarily play by the normal Python rules (only their interfaces are required to, and there are plenty of corner cases even there). So my guess would be that the implementation of the `BINARY_SUBSCR` opcode goes more-or-less *directly* to the underlying C implementations of builtin types that support this operation. For these types, I expect that it is actually `__getitem__` that exists as a Python-level method to wrap the C implementation, rather than that the bracket syntax invokes the Python-level method.

It might be interesting to benchmark `thing.__getitem__(key)` against `thing[key]` for an instance of a custom class that implements `__getitem__`; you might actually see the opposite results there as the `BINARY_SUBSCR` op-code would internally have to fall back to doing equivalent work to looking up the method and invoking it.

Comment: Is []+exception handling faster than `.get()` while providing the same functionality?

Comment: Yes, method with exception handling is the fastest. I've got following results for getting 20 millions entries:
get() : 7.57s
check if key in dict and then use brackets: 7.48s
use brackets with try/except: 5.42s
without checking if key exists at all: 4.68

Comment: @ChrisKoston, how many exceptions did you generate? The performance of `try/except` is asymmetric; when no exception is thrown, it's fast, but when an exception is thrown, it's slow. You should do the same test with more lookup failures.