# Q&A: Defining __getitem__ method or assigning __getitem__ in classes

Tags: python

Which of the below is the recommended way to do `__getitem__`, when it maps to an internal sequence type?

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        self._internal_sequence = []

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._internal_sequence[key]

class B:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        self._internal_sequence = []

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # I'm pretty sure it won't be this one.
        return self._internal_sequence.__getitem__(key)

class C:
    _internal_sequence = []
    __getitem__ = _internal_sequence.__getitem__
```

Answer (score 2):

I realised my answer while writing the question, but I'll still post it here so others can benefit.

C) This appears to work fine, until you realise the _internal_sequence is a class variable and will retain itself between classes. In addition, redefining `_internal_sequence = [...]` seems to remove the `__getitem__` and cause `IndexError`.

B) This doesn't look as nice as A) and for builtin types it will be slower - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10826247/7349206).

Hence, A is the recommended way of mapping a class's `__getitem__` to an internal sequence.