# Why is Python's 'len' function faster than the __len__ method?

Tags: python, python-internals

In Python, `len` is a function to get the length of a collection by calling an object's `__len__` method:

```
def len(x):
    return x.__len__()
```

So I would expect direct call of `__len__()` to be at least as fast as `len()`.

```
import timeit

setup = '''
'''

print (timeit.Timer('a="12345"; x=a.__len__()', setup=setup).repeat(10))
print (timeit.Timer('a="12345"; x=len(a)',      setup=setup).repeat(10))
```

**[Demo link](http://ideone.com/0Egyq7)**

But results of testing with the above code shows `len()` to be faster. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Profiled performance of len(set) vs. set.\_\_len\_\_() in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778691/profiled-performance-of-lenset-vs-set-len-in-python-3)

Comment: @GamesBrainiac That question is about the *opposite* observation.

Comment: Aside: the point of using `setup` is to ensure you're timing only what you're interested in.  If you want to time setting `a` + getting the length instead, that's fine, but you don't need to have a `setup` at all then.

Comment: If length remains unchanged and has to be looked up many times, then store it in an integer `n = len(a)` and use `n`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The builtin `len()` function does not look up the `.__len__` attribute. It looks up the [`tp_as_sequence` pointer](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#tp_as_sequence), which in turn has a [`sq_length` attribute](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#PySequenceMethods.sq_length).

The `.__len__` attribute on built-in objects is indirectly [mapped to the same slot](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/30b3798782f1/Objects/typeobject.c#l6001), and it is that indirection (plus the attribute lookup) that takes more time.

For Python-defined classes, the `type` object looks up the `.__len__` method when the `sq_length` is requested.

Answer (score 3):

From an excellent [Python Object-Oriented Programming: Build robust and maintainable object-oriented Python applications and libraries, 4th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B094DJYLTV) book by Steven F. Lott, and Dusty Phillips

> You may wonder why these objects don't have a length property instead of having to call a function on them. Technically, they do. Most objects that `len()` will apply to have a method called `__len__()` that returns the same value. So `len(myobj)` seems to call `myobj.__len__()`.
>
> Why should we use the `len()` function instead of the `__len__()` method? Obviously, `__len__()` is a special double-underscore method, suggesting that we shouldn't call it directly. There must be an explanation for this. The Python developers don't make such design decisions lightly.
>
> The main reason is efficiency. When we call the `__len__()` method of an object, the object has to look the method up in its namespace, and, if the special `__getattribute__()` method (which is called every time an attribute or method on an object is accessed) is defined on that object, it has to be called as well. Furthermore, the `__getattribute__()` method may have been written to do something clever, for example, refusing to give us access to special methods such as `__len__()`! The `len()` function doesn't encounter any of this. It actually calls the `__len__()` method on the underlying class, so `len(myobj)` maps to `MyObj.__len__(myobj)`.

Answer (score 1):

`__len__` is slower than `len()`, because `__len__` 
involves a dict lookup.

Comment: That raises the question of how `len` can avoid a dict lookup, and I don't think it's particular useful to OP (or anyone else who doesn't already know how) without explaining that as well.