# Dunder Methods verus builtin methods

Tags: python, oop

I have two examples:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = 4

print (a.__len__())
print (len(a))

print(b.__add__(4))
print (b + 4)
```

I guess my question is, is there a difference when using `__len__` magic method versus the built in `len()` method? The only time I see people use `__len__` is when trying to trying to find the length of an object of a user-created class.

Same with other dunder methods, such as `__str__`, or `__add__` I never seem them used outside of a class or OOP in general.

Comment: [yes, there is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712227/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-list#comment18340392_1712236)

Comment: The point of the "magic methods" is to let you customise how your object behaves when used with normal syntax. Sure, you could rewrite every `foo = bar + baz` as `foo = `bar.__add__(baz), but why would you?! Also, I don't think that would invoke delegation where that method isn't implemented, which `+` does.

Answer (score -2):

There are only small differencies. Function is just a function, that call **len**. Something like

```
def len(x):
   return x.__len__()
```

Of course, you can override builtin len, but that is dump (maybe except debugging). Only different thing is len(x) is easier to read, and `x.__len__` allows you create your own implentation of operator. `x.__len__` also can be bit faster, but it is a good reason to use it.

When operator have 2 arguments its implementation do more. `a+b` at first it tries, whether is callable `a.__add__` and if it is not, than tries to call `b.__radd__`.

Comment: [Why Python function `len` is faster than `__len__` method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302558/why-python-function-len-is-faster-than-len-method)