# explanation of C implementation python's len function

Tags: python, c, cpython, python-internals

I was reading about implementation of builtin functions of python when I came across this C implementation of **len** function

```
static PyObject *
builtin_len(PyObject *module, PyObject *obj)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=fa7a270d314dfb6c input=bc55598da9e9c9b5]*/
{
Py_ssize_t res;

res = PyObject_Size(obj);
if (res < 0) {
    assert(PyErr_Occurred());
    return NULL;
}
return PyLong_FromSsize_t(res);
```

I am not able to understand what is going on in this code. I have no idea how C works. Can someone explain what this code is doing?

I got the code from https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c

Edit: I was just curious how len function is so fast and stumbled across this code. I just want to know why function PyObject_Size is used to check size of object is zero and then PyLong_FromSsize_t to return the actual size.

Comment: *"I have no idea how C works"* - then learn it first? SO is not a tutorial service

Comment: "I have no idea how C works" Start by at least getting a basic understanding of C syntax. No one can teach you C within an SO answer

Comment: I was just curious how len function is so fast and stumbled across this code. I am not asking to get a C tutorial. I just wanted to know why function PyObject_Size is used to check size of object is zero and then PyLong_FromSsize_t to return the actual size

Comment: Did you check what those functions do? Do you understand how the Python type system is implemented in CPython? (Hint: you cannot return a `Py_ssize_t` to Python)

Comment: I am not a programmer, I just use python to dabble into data science, machine learning for fun. My intent was not to become a python or CPython expert. I was not aware that I have to be an expert to ask a question on SO. I was just curious. And yes I tried to find implementation of these functions but was not able to.

Comment: The internals of the CPython implementation *are* an expert domain - unless you plan to become an expert on it (or are implementing your own programming language) you won't be able to learn much from glancing at isolated code segments. And explaining these internals is too broad for a SO question

Comment: I referred to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20302670/4652493, and thought that explanation might be as simple as this. But thanks, from now on I will just limit myself to asking questions about errors I am getting and not get into territory of experts. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing special with *this* function. Usually the functions written in C, especially those that do not call Python code, are much faster than ones written in Python.

I am specifically taking the stance here that a reader *knows* how C works, otherwise the explanation would rather be a book.

The `builtin_len` is the one that is called when `len(foo)` is executed in Python code. The `PyObject *obj` argument to the function references the object given as the argument (`foo`), and `PyObject *self` will contain a reference to the containing module of `builtin_len`.

Each container in Python must have a length between 0 and the maximum value allowed by `Py_ssize_t`. `PyObject_Size(obj);` is a function/macro that gets the size of the given object through its `obj->ob_type->tp_as_sequence->sq_length` or `obj->ob_type->tp_as_mapping->mp_length`. Upon error an exception is set as raised for the current thread and a number < 0 (-1) is returned.

The `return NULL;` signifies the caller that an exception has occurred and it must act accordingly - if it is a function call instruction in Python bytecode, it will cause an exception to be raised; if it is C code, then it will behave in a manner similar to this function - returning NULL or invalid value if an exception occurred; or it can clear the exception or replace it with another one.

Otherwise **if greater than or equal to 0**, the `Py_ssize_t res` which is of a C integer type, is converted to a Python *`int`* object, by either returning an existing `int` object or constructing a new one. The Python `int` object is called `PyLong` in CPython 3 for historical reasons. `PyLong_FromSsize_t()` is one of many functions - this one is able to convert any value of type `Py_ssize_t` to a Python `int` with the same value. The reference to this object, like all other objects, are kept as pointers to the (semi-opaque) `PyObject` structure, and this is returned.

The `assert(PyErr_Occurred());` is an assertion that is in effect in debug builds of Python only. It asserts that upon getting a negative number from `PyObject_Size`, signifying an exception being thrown, the exception has also been properly set; if not present, it will abort the entire CPython process outright. It isn't in effect in release builds of Python because "asserts never fail".

Comment: Great answer, but OP **explicitly** writes *"I have no idea how C works"*

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to understand your answer using google to search many terms.