# How len() function is implemented in python 3 and how to find the source code of built in functions in python?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

The quest started from a simple LeetCode problem. I am learning python and trying to solve a problem in leetcode where I have used **len()** while checking the condition in while loop. I got curious if I write **len(nums)** in while will my program do more computations. To find this out I started looking for the source code.

```
while i < len(nums):
       #if both the numbers are same we can pop the ith number
       #else just increase the index and return the length in the end.
       if nums[i] ==  val:
            nums.pop(i)
       else:
           i+=1
return len(nums)
```

Now, I have 2 question:

1. How to look for the source code of **builtin** functions without manually searching the source code on GitHub?
2. How **len** function works internally?

I have 2 assumptions for it:

1. Python treat every thing as an object and they have a property called length(or something like  that) and whenever I pop an element from list. This property get decremented by 1.
2. Another assumption is python in someway iterates over the whole object and return the length.

I got the source code. However, again it's using another function to calculate the length.

```
static PyObject *
builtin_len(PyObject *module, PyObject *obj)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=fa7a270d314dfb6c input=bc55598da9e9c9b5]*/
{
    Py_ssize_t res;

    res = PyObject_Size(obj);
    if (res < 0) {
        assert(PyErr_Occurred());
        return NULL;
    }
    return PyLong_FromSsize_t(res);
}
```

@Antti Haapala did a great job in explaining the answer. However, It doesn't answer my question.

These are some of the relevant question that I found on the stack overflow:

[How to view source code of function in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function)

[explanation of C implementation python's len function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53988132/explanation-of-c-implementation-pythons-len-function)

Comment: "manually searching the source code on GitHub" – well, I mean, use Github's search to find e.g. `PyObject_Size`'s definition? https://github.com/python/cpython/search?q=pyobject_size

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions#:~:text=8%20Answers&text=Since%20Python%20is%20open%20source,in%20the%20documentation%20of%20inspect%20.

Comment: The complexity of getting the length is O(1) (https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) so the source code is not really important for this matter, it's an efficient operation and that's pretty much it. Of course, it's one more instruction, but I highly doubt one instruction will make you fail the leetcode problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Question 0

> I got curious if I write len(nums) in while will my program do more computations.

One aspect of this is documented in the Python wiki's [TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) page for all built-in data structures. `len()` for a list is `O(1)`.

If you mean something along the lines of

> will my program be faster if I do `n = len(nums)`, then manually subtract 1 from `n` each time I remove from the list

then that's a whole other question, and the answer is likely (measure it!) to be (perhaps somewhat unintuitively) "no", since `len()` is implemented in C (fast!) and interpreting Python code (`n -= 1`) and executing it is slower.

## Question 1

> How to look for the source code of builtin functions without manually searching the source code on GitHub?

As prerequisites, you will need to

- know how to read C and understand the control flow
- be able to keep track of the call graph (in your head, in a text file, on a notepad)
- have an intuition of where you start looking in the source code

GitHub's source code search is, well, passable, but you'll have a better time downloading the source and using a better IDE to jump around in the code.

For built-in functions in modules, I'd start searching for e.g. `mathmodule.c` for the math functions, etc.

For implementations of objects, there's e.g. `listobject.c`. It's fairly logical (most of the time).

## Question 2

1. You already found `builtin_len`.
2. You can see it calls `PyObject_Size`. That's defined [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ce5e1a6809b714eb0383219190a076d9f883e008/Objects/abstract.c#L53).
3. It does `PySequenceMethods *m = Py_TYPE(o)->tp_as_sequence;`, i.e. grabs a pointer to the type header of the object, and the "slot" (not to be confused with the Python userland slots) of the sequence-related methods for the object.
4. If that method collection contains a valid `sq_length()` function, it is called: `Py_ssize_t len = m->sq_length(o);` If that length is valid, it is returned, and `len()` wraps the bare `size_t` into a Python long object and passes it to you.
5. If that fails, [`PyMapping_Size`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ce5e1a6809b714eb0383219190a076d9f883e008/Objects/abstract.c#L2317) gets called.
6. It does a similar thing as the `sq_length` stuff, only using mapping methods, `tp_as_mapping` and `mp_length`.
7. If all that fails, a TypeError is raised using the `type_error()` helper.

[Here in `listobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ce5e1a6809b714eb0383219190a076d9f883e008/Objects/listobject.c#L2797-L2798), you can see how [`list_length()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ce5e1a6809b714eb0383219190a076d9f883e008/Objects/listobject.c#L417) is hooked up to be `sq_length` for list objects.

That function only calls `Py_SIZE()`[https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.Py_SIZE], which is a macro to access the `ob_size` field which all [PyVarObject](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyVarObject)s have.

The documentation on find how Python's list objects use `ob_size` is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Include/cpython/listobject.h#L10-L21).

As for how a custom type with `__len__` hooks up into all of this, my recollection is that objects with `__len__` will have their `sq_length()` call the Python callable, if one exists, and that value is then "trampolined" back through the C code back to your Python code.

Comment: Thanks, It's a great answer. As you have mentioned I had implemented it using the manual method as well in my submission. However, not shared it here. LeetCode displayed execution time is not reliable and I don't know how to test the speed of a program. So, as of now I can't test it. I am happy to know in short that len takes O(1) rather than O(n). Follow up question: As the time displayed on the website is for list or in general for any type of built in data type.

Comment: "I don't know how to test the speed of a program." The simplest is the [built-in `timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/timeit.html#module-timeit).

Comment: "As the time displayed on the website is for list or in general for any type of built in data type." The page has subheaders for lists, deques, dicts, and sets.

Comment: Lol, I totally get there are subheaders, However length is not mentioned in other data types and what about tuples.

Comment: Well, my post did give you the tools to figure that out yourself, but: tuple: `Py_SIZE()`, constant. dict: `((PyDictObject *)mp)->ma_used`, constant. set: `(((PySetObject *)(so))->used`, constant. deques: `Py_SIZE()`, constant.