# Why Does None Give Inconsistent Results for Dunder Methods?

Tags: python, arrays, oop, vector, null

From the documentations of python dunder methods, I was led to believe, for any object, the methods and the corresponding function/operator call are equivalent. In particular, I believed `someobject.__len__()` is same as `len(someobject)`. But only recently I realised it does not hold for `None`.

```
None.__len__() # Throws AttributeError
len(None) # Throws TypeError
```

Does not it violate the API equivalence? It is obvious both should throw an error, but I would have expected line two to throw an `AtrributeError` as well if it is getting *translated* into line one under the hood.

I wonder if there are other special cases like this I should be aware of, or my entire assumption about dunder methods is wrong? When is the function call exactly faithful to the dunder method, and when it is not? Also, I wonder if it is a deliberate design decision of the language for some reason (would be curious why).

Comment: I would not expect `AttributeError`.  That is just an implementation detail.  Note that the same thing happens for user-define classes, unless you add the `__len__` method yourself:  `class O:` / `pass` / `o = O()` / `len(o)`.

Comment: Yes, in user defined classes, I (the developer) will define ```__len__()``` which will be called as proxy for ```len()```. But the above example leads me to believe this equivalence of ```len()``` and ```__len__()``` holds for *only developer defined* classes. Or even that is not completely true?

Comment: @Della It's actually other way round. `len()` calls `__len__()` in some instances. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20302670/9296093) explains it pretty well.

Comment: It's not an equivalence at all.  If `__len__` is defined, `len` calls it.  If `__len__` is not defined, it's a TypeError.